# Universal property of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

[I know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12009/572841) $\mathbb R$ is - up to a unique isomorphism of ordered fields - the unique complete ordered field. Is there a similar characterization of the complex numbers? I guess that $\mathbb C$ can not simply be defined as a field with particular properties, but that additional structure must be part of the definition.$^1$

Anyways, I am sure that many people have thought about this issue and that there are several possible approaches. I would like to learn about them.

---

$^1$ E.g. two functions from $\mathbb C$ onto $\mathbb R$ (the projection onto the real part and the projection onto the imaginary part).

Comment: I don't think you can get away from the fact that complex conjugation is an automorphism of $\mathbb C$. That means you'll never have a unique isomorphism.

Comment: @eyeballfrog [In this paper](https://doi.org/10.1080/0025570X.1970.11976006) $\mathbb C$ is introduced as a field $F$ together with an automorphism $F\ni z\mapsto \overline{z}\in F$ and an ordering on the set $\{z:\overline{z}=z\}$. And indeed this does only define $\mathbb C$ up to "duique" isomorphism (see theorem 6).

Answer (score 4):

Up to "duique" isomorphism (there are two of them), it is the only algebraic closure of $\Bbb R$. I don't think you can do unique, as complex conjugation will always be present.

Comment: We can only count the fields up to isomorphism anyway, since we don't want $\mathbb{R}(i)$ to be different from $\mathbb{R}(\square)$ just using the symbol $\square$ in place of $i$. So the automorphism doesn't matter - there's just the one field.

Comment: @aschepler Sure, but even though there are plenty of candidate _objects_, the uniqueness of any isomorphism between them would still often be a desirable property. For instance, a product object in a given category (if it exists) is very much non-unique, but for any two objects that satisfy the role of $X\times Y$, there is only a single isomorphism between them that work with the projection maps. Not so in this case.

Comment: By that logic, doesn't $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ describe two fields?

Comment: @aschepler No. I have no idea what that even means. But it means that if you have another field $F$, and $F\cong \Bbb Q[x]/(x^2-2)$, then there are _two_ isomorphisms $F \to Q[x]/(x^2-2)$, as $x\mapsto -x$ yields an automorphism of $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2-2)$. Since the question specifically asked about _unique_ isomorphisms, I felt it apt to address the fact that no, you can't get unique isomorphisms this way, there will always be two.

Comment: So the statement is essentially "all fields with property $P$ are isomorphic to each other, and do not have non-trivial automorphisms"?

Comment: @aschepler That is one way to describe what the phrase "up to unique isomorphism" captures, yes. I'm sure there are subtleties that would make them not entirely 100% equivalent phrases, but they are definitely closely related.

Comment: When we say that $\mathbb C$ is an algebraic closure of  $\mathbb R$, this means in particular that $\mathbb C$ is a field $F$ together with a field homomorphism $\mathbb R\to F$ (apart from that, no additional structure), right?

Comment: @Filippo That's what field extension means, yes. The algebraic closure is just a very particular field extension, it has no structure apart from that, no.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1626950/113214) notes that up to isomorphism there is only one field that is a vector space of dimension 2 over $\mathbb R$. Does that count as characterizing $\mathbb C$ up to isomorphism?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be precise, it characterizes $\mathbb C$
 up to "duique" isomorphism (not unique), right? So my answer to your question would be "no", but I still consider your answer useful (+1), just like Arthur's answer.

Comment: In fact it looks like some people think that $\mathbb C$ can not be defined up to a unique isomorphism, so maybe I have to be content with this.